# Sums of $\Lambda(n)$ or $\mu(n)$ with hyperbolic-function weights: surprise!

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I was leafing through Gradshteyn–Ryzhik in bed yesterday, as one does, and noticed on the last page that the Mellin transforms of several hyperbolic functions have a factor of $\zeta(s-1)$ or $\zeta(s)$ in them. (That turns out to be very easy to prove — for the functions in that table and several other ones.) That has the following immediate consequence.

If you work out
$$\sum \left(1- \tanh\left(\frac{n}{x}\right)\right) \mu(n)$$ (say) or
$$\sum \left(1- \tanh\left(\frac{n}{x}\right) \right) \Lambda(n),$$
you will find out that everything turns out beautifully: the zeros of $\zeta(s)$ have no effect, and you get an unconditional expression as a nice, closed-form power series on $x^{-1}$.

I am told (by a non-analytic-number-theorist) that this is known, and a colleague (who *is* an analytic number theorist) points out that there is a variant that is trivial: $$
\sum_n \frac{\mu(n)}{1-e^{n/x}} = \sum_d \sum_n e^{dn/x} \mu(n) = 1.$$

Still, I'm a bit surprised. Are there any applications?

Comment: I think MO titles should generally avoid clickbait-y tricks ("you won't believe the behaviour of these weighted sums!"), but I quite like this one.

Comment: The identity $\sum_n \lfloor \frac{x}{n} \rfloor \Lambda(n) = \log(x!)$ (for $x$ an integer) quickly implies Mertens' theorem $\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\Lambda(n)}{n} = \log x + O(1)$; similarly $\sum_n \lfloor \frac{x}{n} \rfloor \mu(n) = 1$ implies $|\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}| \leq 1$.  That's about the level of what one can accomplish with these sorts of convolution identities between $\mu$ or $\Lambda$ on one hand, and a weight which implicitly involves Dirichlet convolution with the indicator function of the natural numbers on the other (to kill all the contributions of zeta zeroes).

Comment: @Terry Tao: Right, that was part of what I was wondering: can one give a nice, elegant proof of something like that using these weights? Of course there might be a nice, elegant proof of something else as well. I'm not sure "that's about the level" has a rigorous meaning here. In fact the main obstruction to getting meaningful Chebyshev-type bounds out of this seems to be $\Gamma(s)$, which decreases exponentially as $|\Im s|$ grows -- not $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: Given that you are explicitly cancelling out the contribution of the zeroes, I would say that one should only expect to prove results that are insensitive to the location of the zeroes; for instance one would not expect to prove the prime number theorem this way (without some deep Tauberian theorem or something which amounts to establishing non-vanishing of $\zeta(1+it)$).  But statements that relate only to the behavior of $\zeta$ near $s=1$ should be attainable from such identities (Mertens' theorem, for instance, is of this form).

Comment: My guess though that your hyperbolic tangent type weights are so smooth that it would be difficult to extract much information from them directly (the identities you mention are likely just smoothly averaged versions of the identities I mentioned previously).  On the Fourier side this corresponds to the issue with the decay of the Gamma function that you mentioned.  In general it is the rough averages which are the powerful ones - compare the prime number theorem $\sum_{n \leq x} \Lambda(n) = x+o(x)$ with Mertens' theorem $\sum_{n \leq x} \Lambda(n)/n = \log x + O(1)$, for instance.

Comment: Sure - but can one prove estimates of the type $|\sum_{n\leq x} \mu(n)|\leq \epsilon x$ in this way? Explicit estimates of that sort are surprisingly tricky. (Until very recently, the best results of that kind were elementary, in the style of Chebyshev; people were having real difficulties with a direct analytic approach.)

Comment: One can get elementary proofs of $|\sum_{n \leq x} \Lambda(n) - x| \leq \varepsilon x$ for any $\varepsilon>0$ and sufficiently large $x$ by convolving the identity $\sum_{n} \lfloor \frac{x}{n} \rfloor \Lambda(n) = \log \lfloor x\rfloor!$ with a carefully chosen finite weight depending on $\varepsilon$ in the spirit of Chebyshev, see e.g., Section 9
 of https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-7/issue-3/Elementary-methods-in-the-study-of-the-distribution-of-prime/bams/1183549769.full .  I would expect the story is similar for Mobius.

Comment: Besides, while this sort of nearly-trivial observation is itself insensitive to the location of zeros, our application of it need not be. For instance, we could do a Mellin convolution of one of these functions $g$ with a function $f$ that we have cunningly defined so that its Mellin transform on a segment $[1--i T, 1+i T]$ is about $1/M g$. Of course we are then using the fact that $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros on $\Re s = 1$ (otherwise $f$ would not exist), though we are not invoking that fact directly; we are just constructing a function.

Comment: (That doesn't really work, but that's because of the factor of $\Gamma(s)$ in these Mellin transforms, not because of the $\zeta$ factor.)

Comment: Yes, this partial deconvolution strategy is more or less exactly what is done in Section 9 of the survey paper of Diamond that I just listed, but again for the identity involving convolution with a rough weight.  Convolving with a smooth weight conveys much less information and so would be harder to use (one has to do much more deconvolution); perhaps with some herculean effort one could replicate these arguments with such weights, but I don't see much advantage in trying to do so.

Comment: Right - it's the $\Gamma(s)$ factor that spoils things, and that comes from the exponential bit.

Comment: Tim Browning points out a very close connection between the above and Lambert series.